# Caffe - Use VGG network layers as 'end' objectives and generate dreams on input-image

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe, deep-dream

> **MODEL**

I have been trying to train a `VGG_FACE_16_layers` Net from scratch, following the steps on this project: 
https://github.com/danduncan/HappyNet

Then I trained a face/emotion recognition model on a cloud GPU, from my `mdb` files, and produced a file `my_face.caffemodel.`

It has 6 labels, and although prediction accuracy is not optimal, model seems to be usable.

```
net = caffe.Net('models/vitor_face/deploy.prototxt', 
                 'models/vitor_face/my_face.caffemodel', 
                 caffe.TEST)

W = net.params['fc7'][0].data[...]
b = net.params['fc7'][1].data[...]
```

`W`'s and `b`'s for all layers seem to print valid values.

and the architecture:

```
[('data', (1, 3, 224, 224)), ('conv1', (1, 96, 111, 111)), ('norm1', (1, 96, 111, 111)), ('pool1', (1, 96, 37, 37)), ('conv2', (1, 256, 37, 37)), ('pool2', (1, 256, 19, 19)), ('conv3', (1, 512, 19, 19)), ('conv4', (1, 512, 19, 19)), ('conv5', (1, 512, 19, 19)), ('pool5', (1, 512, 7, 7)), ('fc6', (1, 4048)), ('fc7', (1, 4048)), ('fc8', (1, 6)), ('prob', (1, 6))]
[('conv1', (96, 3, 7, 7), (96,)), ('conv2', (256, 96, 5, 5), (256,)), ('conv3', (512, 256, 3, 3), (512,)), ('conv4', (512, 512, 3, 3), (512,)), ('conv5', (512, 512, 3, 3), (512,)), ('fc6', (4048, 25088), (4048,)), ('fc7', (4048, 4048), (4048,)), ('fc8_cat', (6, 4048), (6,))]
```

---

> **OBJECTIVE**

My aim is to use layers from a `network` as `objective ends` in order to generate `dreams`, and make the faces used for training "appear" on a input image, using this code:

```
model_path = 'happyNet/models/vitor_face/' # substitute your path here
net_fn   = model_path + 'deploy.prototxt'
param_fn = model_path + 'my_face.caffemodel'
MEAN_FILE = model_path + 'mean_training_image.binaryproto'

proto_data = open(MEAN_FILE, "rb").read()
a = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.BlobProto.FromString(proto_data)
MEAN = caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(a)[0]


net = caffe.Classifier(net_fn, 
                        param_fn,
                        mean = np.float32([104.0, 116.0, 122.0]), # ImageNet mean, training set dependent
                        channel_swap = (2,1,0)) # ImageNet mean, training set dependent) # the reference model has channels in BGR order instead of RGB

# a couple of utility functions for converting to and from Caffe's input image layout
def preprocess(net, img):
    return np.float32(np.rollaxis(img, 2)[::-1]) - net.transformer.mean['data']
def deprocess(net, img):
    return np.dstack((img + net.transformer.mean['data'])[::-1])

def objective_L2(dst):
    dst.diff[:] = dst.data 

def make_step(net, step_size=1.5, end='fc7', 
              jitter=32, clip=True, objective=objective_L2):
    '''Basic gradient ascent step.'''

    src = net.blobs['data'] # input image is stored in Net's 'data' blob
    dst = net.blobs[end]
    #print ('src.data', src.data)
    # print  ('PERCENTILE',np.percentile(net.blobs[end].data[0], (0, 10, 50, 90, 100)))

    ox, oy = np.random.randint(-jitter, jitter+1, 2)
    src.data[0] = np.roll(np.roll(src.data[0], ox, -1), oy, -2) # apply jitter shift

    net.forward(end=end)
    objective(dst)  # specify the optimization objective
    net.backward(start=end)
    g = src.diff[0]
    # apply normalized ascent step to the input image
    src.data[:] += step_size/np.abs(g).mean() * g

    src.data[0] = np.roll(np.roll(src.data[0], -ox, -1), -oy, -2) # unshift image

    if clip:
        bias = net.transformer.mean['data']
        src.data[:] = np.clip(src.data, -bias, 255-bias)

def deepdream(net, base_img, iter_n=20, octave_n=4, octave_scale=1.4, 
              end='fc7', clip=True, **step_params):
    # prepare base images for all octaves
    octaves = [preprocess(net, base_img)]

    for i in xrange(octave_n-1):
        octaves.append(nd.zoom(octaves[-1], (1, 1.0/octave_scale,1.0/octave_scale), order=1))

    src = net.blobs['data']
    #print src.data
    # print blobs infos
    print [(k, v.data.shape) for k, v in net.blobs.items()]
    #print weight and bias parameters
    print [(k, v[0].data.shape, v[1].data.shape) for k, v in net.params.items()]

    detail = np.zeros_like(octaves[-1]) # allocate image for network-produced details

    for octave, octave_base in enumerate(octaves[::-1]):
        h, w = octave_base.shape[-2:]

        if octave > 0:
            # upscale details from the previous octave
            h1, w1 = detail.shape[-2:]
            detail = nd.zoom(detail, (1, 1.0*h/h1,1.0*w/w1), order=1)

        src.reshape(1,3,h,w) # resize the network's input image size
        src.data[0] = octave_base+detail

        for i in xrange(20):
            make_step(net, end=end, clip=clip, **step_params)

            # visualization
            vis = deprocess(net, src.data[0])

            if not clip: # adjust image contrast if clipping is disabled
                vis = vis*(255.0/np.percentile(vis, 99.98))
            showarray(vis)
            # save images to disk
            PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(vis)).save('results/{}_{}_{}.png'.format(octave, i, vis.shape))

            print octave, i, end, vis.shape
            clear_output(wait=True)

        # extract details produced on the current octave
        detail = src.data[0]-octave_base
    # returning the resulting image
    return deprocess(net, src.data[0])
```

and then run it, expecting to make trained faces appear on a cloud image, like so:

```
img = np.float32(PIL.Image.open('img/clouds.jpg'))

_=deepdream(net, img, end)
```

> **RELEVANT FILES**

*deploy.prototxt*

```
name: "VGG_FACE_16_layers"
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 224
input_dim: 224
layers {
  name: "conv1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 7
    stride: 2
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        # distribution with stdev 0.01 (default mean: 0)
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" # initialize the biases to zero (0)
        value: 0
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu1"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layers {
  name: "norm1"
  type: LRN
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0005
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layers {
  name: "pool1"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 3
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv2"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 1
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu2"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layers {
  name: "pool2"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv3"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 0
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu3"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layers {
  name: "conv4"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 1
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu4"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layers {
  name: "conv5"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 0
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu5"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layers {
  name: "pool5"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 3
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc6"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4048
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.005        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 1
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu6"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layers {
  name: "drop6"
  type: DROPOUT
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc7"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4048
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 0
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu7"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layers {
  name: "drop7"
  type: DROPOUT
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc8_cat"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 6
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 0
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "prob"
  type: SOFTMAX
  bottom: "fc8"
  top: "prob"
}
```

*train.prototxt*

```
name: "CaffeNet"
layers {
  name: "training_train"
  type: DATA
  data_param {
    source: "/input/training_set_lmdb"
    backend: LMDB
    batch_size: 32
  }
  transform_param{
    mean_file: "/input/mean_training_image.binaryproto"
  }
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
layers {
  name: "training_test"
  type: DATA
  data_param {
    source: "/input/validation_set_lmdb"
    backend: LMDB
    batch_size: 15
  }
  transform_param{
    mean_file: "/input/mean_training_image.binaryproto"
  }
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 96
    kernel_size: 7
    stride: 2
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 0
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu1"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layers {
  name: "norm1"
  type: LRN
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "norm1"
  lrn_param {
    local_size: 5
    alpha: 0.0005
    beta: 0.75
  }
}
layers {
  name: "pool1"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "norm1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 3
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv2"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 256
    pad: 2
    kernel_size: 5
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 1
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu2"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layers {
  name: "pool2"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv3"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 0
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu3"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layers {
  name: "conv4"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv4"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu4"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layers {
  name: "conv5"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv5"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 512
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 1
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu5"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layers {
  name: "pool5"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 3
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc6"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "fc6"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4048
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.005
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "relu6"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
}
layers {
  name: "drop6"
  type: DROPOUT
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc6"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc7"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "fc6"
  top: "fc7"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 4048
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 0
      }
  }

}
layers {
  name: "relu7"
  type: RELU
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
}
layers {
  name: "drop7"
  type: DROPOUT
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc7"
  dropout_param {
    dropout_ratio: 0.5
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc8_cat"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "fc7"
  top: "fc8_cat"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 6
    weight_filler {
        type: "gaussian" 
        std: 0.01        
      }
      bias_filler {
        type: "constant" 
        value: 0
      }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "prob"
  type: SOFTMAX_LOSS
  bottom: "fc8_cat"
  bottom: "label"
}
```

> **TRACEBACKS**

The code above works with pretrained nets, but not with mine, trained from scratch.

Somehow it looks like net is not being forwarded all the way, because
   I get this traceback of some zero divides, like so:

```
   dream.py:178: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
    src.data[:] += step_size/np.abs(g).mean() * g
    dream.py:178: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
    src.data[:] += step_size/np.abs(g).mean() * g
```

(result image is totally black, and if I manually add to bias - `g+.1`, I just print the original image, not transformed at all.)

Also, I get the following `InnerProduct` warning, that hints that my
   `input_dim` could be wrong at classification layers, but I don't
   understand why nor how this could be, since the original project uses
   `input_dim 224,224`:

```
>275 inner_product_layer.cpp:64] Check failed: K_ == new_K (25088 vs. 20480) Input size incompatible with inner product parameters.
```

Anyway I've tried to change `input_dim` at `deploy.prototxt` to AlexNet's value `227`, but to no avail.

> **OBS**
>   Since I want to use my model in order to generate dreams and not classify images, I wonder if I should try and make the model `FullyConnected` all the way up classification layers, as suggested on this answer:
>
> [Caffe: variable input-image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697519/caffe-variable-input-image-size?rq=1)
>
> If this is the way to go in order make the model compatible with GoogLeNet architecture and activate `=end` layers from my model, can please somebody tell me how to do it?

**Please, ANY help would be really appreciated**

I would gladly share my model via chat by request.

Comment: See [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/caffe-users/uhp2zc6ap8o/HWyVuAt1hWYJ).

Comment: yes, had seen it. thats where i took the Fully connected mention from.